# Canon EOS t3i software on EOS T5

Tags: software, firmware

Would it be possible to install the T3i software on my T5 (1200D)? Both cameras have the same Digic-4 CPU. The reason I'm asking this is that the T3i have some features for video my T5 doesn't have.

Comment: Not really because I'm talking about installing an older firmware, not a more recent firmware

Comment: My understanding is you want to install firmware from one more to other model. And I have my doubts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, T3i firmware will not install on your T5.  Firmware is always very specific to each camera model.

[Magic Lantern](https://magiclantern.fm/) is a free 3rd party firmware add-on that is available for many different Canon DSLRs.  It unlocks many hidden features, but it is not yet fully developed for the T5/1200D.